# How to open a hard drive in an hex editor on Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hex-editor

How can I can open a whole hard drive on Windows with an hex editor ? I use wxHexEditor, on Linux I just have to open the `/dev/sdX` file but I don't think such a file exist on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general answer for all hex editors, not every hex editors supports that option.
Some offer you a special menu item to open a harddrive.
There is a special combination of symbols like "\." or similar to open a device - can'
t find the exact writing anymore. That could be a possibility if the file dialogue supports that selection.

Comment: Ok, effectively there is an option in ```Devices → Open disk device``` in wxHexEditor to open a hard drive on Windows. But the software has to be opened as administrator first.

Comment: You did not mention not having administrator rights. If you don't have them ask the responsable person to give you those rights. If you don't get them there is a reason for it. :)

Comment: A great disk hex editor is integrated in most of 3rd party Partition tools like Acronis Disk Director, Paragon Partition Manager and Active@ Partition Manager